# How to create RESTful service with customizable notification in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new to spring, but not new to java.

I'd like to create base class for all REST services that would send notification through some messaging protocol on requests with chosen methods (POST, PUT, PACTCH) (when resource is changed basically)

So for example If I would create interface

```
public interface RestService<T, I> {

    T get(I id);
    T create();
    T patch(I id);
    T put(I id);
}
```

How can I use that in spring RestController and somehow decorate it with notifications?
All this spring @Autowire and configuration files is somewhat confusing to me, because while I'm familiar with dependency injection and used constructor dependency injection I haven't used IOC much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best option for you will be to use Spring AOP and put some annotation to the required methods. Please check this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use any interface or base class for any restcontroller or for any other Spring stereotype. The annotations are just clues for Spring itself to use the class as an endpoint for a rest service for example. Your class otherwise can be anything, like:

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService; //If you use the spring sterotypes you dont need to do anything to use a bean but just to use the autowired annotation
}

@RestController
class AnyotherController extends AbstractController {...}

@RestController
class YetAnotherController extends AbstractController implements Something {}
```

Are all valid resources (i.e. web-components) for Spring to use.

Comment: could you elaborate about how to use Autowired in my case? Because now I have  No qualifying bean of type [demo.model.AdcSettingsService] found for dependency error.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?